# how to execute a function inside the process function of godot every 1min?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I need to implement to deduction coin for every 1 minute from user.

I would do this `Player.gd`

```
var game_started = false
var time_start = 0
var time_now = 0
func _process(delta):
   if game_started == true:
   //deduct_one_coin_every_one_minute(uid)

func start(pos):
    print("clicked start the game");
    time_start = OS.get_unix_time()
    set_process(true)
    game_started = true
```

How to call or execute a function `deduct_one_coin_every_one_minute(uid)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would probably best be solved with a [Timer](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_timer.html) node. You can add it to your scene either in the scene editor or in your code, and connect the `timeout` signal to your `deduct_one_coin_every_one_minute()`  function. Then, set the `wait_time` to 60 and call `start()`.